# How can I simplify this expression so that a value of $0$ is allowable for the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The expression is in the form:

$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.
$$

And

$$
f(x)=x^2-2x.
$$

They don't tell me what $f(h)$ is equal to and I don't know if it's valid for me to substitute $f(h)$ as $h$. In any case the furthest I get is:

$$
\frac{(x^2-2x+h)-(x^2-2x)}h=\frac{(x(x-2)+h)-x(x-2)}h
$$

And that's as far as I get. The answer key says the solution is: $-2 + h + 2x$

I have no idea how that solution was arrived at.

As a secondary question, am I correct in assuming that $f(x + h)$ is the same as saying $f(x) + f(h)$? And if I'm correct in that, then can the expression from this problem be phrased $f((x + h) - x) / h$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)=x^2-2x$, you have
$$
f(x+h)=(x+h)^2-2(x+h)=x^2+2xh+h^2-2x-2h\tag1\label{1}
$$and so
$$
f(x+h)-f(x)=2xh+h^2-2h,
$$
and you get from this that
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=2x+h-2.
$$
Besides, it is clear from \eqref{1} that $f(x+h)\ne f(x)+f(h)$.

Comment: Ah I knew I was missing something. I just got done learning about functions but they didn't cover how this syntax works. I had a feeling I was missing something big. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

When it writes $f(x) = x^2 - 2 x$ (without specifying any restriction on $x$) it means that this equation is true for arbitrary $x$.  Thus to get $f(anything)$ you can substitute $anything$ for $x$.

No, it is certainly **not** true that $f(x+h) = f(x) + f(h)$.  Instead, to get $f(x+h)$ you substitute $x+h$ for $x$ in the equation for $f(x)$.

Expand everything out, and you should find that all terms of $f(x+h) - f(x)$ have an $h$ in them, so you can cancel the $h$ in numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation